# Symfony 2 - Redirect() to Specified Page

Tags: symfony

I am trying to redirect Symfony to another route `/404` if there is a 404 error. In the `ExceptionController.php` file, I am looking for the error code 404. When error 404 is present, redirect to `my-domain.com/404`. I want to redirect my users to another 404 page is because my custom 404 page is from another bundle.

Below is the code I have written. When I go to a non-existing website, I am presented with a 500 server error page instead of my expected redirected 404 page. Am I missing something?

```
if ($code == '404') {
    return $this->redirect("/404");
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html)?

Comment: @Squazic Yup, I have looked at that. Symfony is my first framework, and I just stated working on it recently. I am still confused and reading the docs. I am looking at the Redirection section (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html) for guidance.

Comment: @Squazic I was able to create a custom error page following the guide you posted. However, I need to place this custom 404 page in another section of my website. That is why I was thinking of redirecting the user to `/404`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a look, and as far as I know it's not possible to have error pages within a 
bundle. It has to be a site wide one found in `app/Resources/views/Exception/error404.html.twig`

However you can return a custom Response by leveraging the HttpFoundation component

```
<?php

namespace Acme\WhateverBundle\Controller;

//...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    //...
    public function takeAction()
    {
        //..

        if ($notFound) {
            $twig = $this->container->get('templating');

            $content = $twig->render('AcmeAnotherBundle:Exception:error404.html.twig');

            return new Response($content, 404, array('Content-Type', 'text/html'));   
        }

        // ...

        return $this->render('AcmeWhateverBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269731/symfony-2-cannot-find-forward

Comment: Looking at your code, how would I integrate that into the existing `symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php`?

Comment: I think in my other post, I was going your direction where I would return a custom response by using `forward()` to transparently redirect the user to my 404 page. Would this approach bypass the fact that an error page cannot live in a bundle and has to be site wide?

Comment: Yes it will, give it a try. I think you can use the forward() method too if it returns a 404 to the client. Also, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You might try using Symfony's createNotFoundException() method:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html#managing-errors-and-404-pages

Instead of redirecting to a 404 page, try this in your controller:

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('This page does not exist.');
```

Comment: When I throw an exception, how does the code know which error page to display? Sorry, I am still very confused and new to frameworks, php, symfony and such.

Comment: That specific exception will throw a 404 error.  You can then customize the 404 error page(and other error pages) as Squazic suggested.  If you are new to PHP, learning symfony2 is quite a task.  It sounds like you're doing okay, but keep in mind that there is a learning curve on symfony for even experienced php developers, let alone a new one.

Comment: @icu222much Symfony2 is very powerful and has its own algorithm for finding the correct error page automatically, [as described in this section here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#customizing-the-404-page-and-other-error-pages), just as long as it's named correctly. You can even use json instead of html for the 404, which you would use if you were for example using jQuery to make AJAX calls to your Symfony app.

Comment: @Mike Sorry, I think I am not explaining myself properly or I am misunderstanding you. I have an existing error page located in another directory rather then in the default Symfony Exceptions folder. I also have successfully over-written Symfony's default error page with a simple error page saying '404 error'.

Comment: @Adam-E I have gone through that page, and have successfully over-written Symfony's default error pages. My problem, however, is that my custom error page must be located in another directory/bundle. I have already written a route `404` in that bundle's controller to link it to my custom 404 page. Would it not be possible to simply forward or redirect the user to `/404` ?

Comment: @icu222much Ah, ok I see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Adam-E Is there a solution for what I am trying to do?

Comment: sure, just gonna test it out first ;)