# Symfony 2 - Cannot find Forward()

Tags: symfony

I am trying to forward my users to a custom 404 page which is located in another bundle. I have modified my `ExceptionController` and attempted to `forward()` the page to my other Error controller which is routed to my custom 404 page.

I receive the error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::forward() in /home/notroot/www/store/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php on line 50`

I am modifying the file `store\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController.php`.

I have added the following lines to ExceptionController.php:

```
if ($code == '404') {
    $response = $this->forward('ItemBundle:Error:pageNotFound');
    return $response;
}
```

ExceptionController.php:

```
public function showAction(FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null, $format = 'html')
{
    $this->container->get('request')->setRequestFormat($format);

    $currentContent = $this->getAndCleanOutputBuffering();

    $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
    $code = $exception->getStatusCode();


    if ($code == '404') {
        $response = $this->forward('ItemBundle:Error:pageNotFound');
        return $response;
    }

    return $templating->renderResponse(
        $this->findTemplate($templating, $format, $code, $this->container->get('kernel')->isDebug()),
        array(
            'status_code'    => $code,
            'status_text'    => isset(Response::$statusTexts[$code]) ? Response::$statusTexts[$code] : '',
            'exception'      => $exception,
            'logger'         => $logger,
            'currentContent' => $currentContent,
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the `forward()` function with the shortcut it points to as stated in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html#forwarding).

```
if ($code == '404') {
    $httpKernel = $this->container->get('http_kernel');
    $response = $httpKernel->forward(
        'ItemBundle:Error:pageNotFound'
    );
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController` doesn't extend the framework Controller normally used in user bundles. Also it's never a good idea to directly edit anything stored in the `vendor` directory.

Comment: +1 for not modifying files in /vendor.  Any time you go to update your vendor files via composer, your changes are going to be lost.